# why isn't cmake respecting LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

System:

```
Windows 10
CMake version 3.26.3
MSVC Build Tools for Visual Studio 17
MSVC version: 19.32.31332.0
```

I have a very simple test case of a project laid out as follows

```
- projectdir
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - libmain.cpp
```

With the following contents

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(helloworld)
add_library(hellolib SHARED "libmain.cpp")
set_target_properties(hellolib PROPERTIES LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

```
// libmain.cpp
#include <iostream>
__declspec(dllexport) void hello_world() {std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;}
```

I build the project as follows, starting with a terminal window in the root directory of the project:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

Given the `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` setting I was expecting the dll to be placed in `projectdir/bin`, or maybe `projectdir/bin/Debug`

However, the dll is instead placed in `projectdir/build/Debug` which is what would happen without the `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` setting.  Am I doing something wrong here?  Building the same project on Mac OSX yields the expected results with `libhellolib.dylib` showing up in `projectdir/bin` so I think I've set the variables correctly but they are not being respected on Windows, and I'm wondering why.

Comment: Perhaps you are the heir to Rodney Dangerfield?

Comment: On Windows location of created dll is controlled by RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY property: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#runtime-output-artifacts